# Get the second value in the row if the dates match in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am in the trouble of getting the values which have the same dates from two different data sources in R. The code is

```
  #Monthly data
  month_data <- c(580.11, 618.25, 641.24, 604.85, 580.86, 580.07, 632.97, 
                  685.09, 754.50, 680.30, 698.37, 707.38, 480.11, 528.25,
                  541.24, 614.85, 680.86)

  month_dates <- seq(as.Date("2001/06/01"), by = "1 months", length = 17) 

  month_data <- data.frame(month_dates, month_data)

  #the dates_for_match is a list: 

dates_for_match<-list(c( "2001-08-01","2001-09-01", "2001-10-01"),c("2001-11-01","2001-12-01","2002-01-01"),c("2002-02-01","2002-03-01","2002-04-01"),c("2002-05-01","2002-06-01","2002-07-01"),c( "2002-08-01","2002-09-01", "2002-10-01"))
```

Example:

```
  > dates_for_match
[[1]]
[1] "2001-08-01" "2001-09-01" "2001-10-01"

[[2]]
[1] "2001-11-01" "2001-12-01" "2002-01-01"

[[3]]
[1] "2002-02-01" "2002-03-01" "2002-04-01"

[[4]]
[1] "2002-05-01" "2002-06-01" "2002-07-01"

[[5]]
[1] "2002-08-01" "2002-09-01" "2002-10-01"
```

I want to use the **dates_for_match** list to get the values from month_data that have the same dates.

Comment: Your  `dates_for_match` is a list not a data.frame

Comment: Thanks for editing and telling me this. Can you give me a hand on this?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Since you are quite new here, you might want to read the [**about**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [**FAQ**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) sections of the website to help you get the most out of it. If an answer does solve your problem you may want to *consider* upvoting and/or marking it as accepted to show the question has been answered, by ticking the little green check mark next to the suitable answer. You are **not** obliged to do this, but it helps keep the site clean of unanswered questions and rewards those who take the time to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need `%in%`...

```
month_data[ month_dates %in% unlist( dates_for_match ) , 2 ]
```